# Как проверить является ли символ числом?

Tags: c#

Как можно проверить,является ли определенный  символ в строке числом? Не смог найти никакой рабочей информации, Parse не работает

Comment: Char.IsDigit - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Char.IsNumber - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber?view=netframework-4.7.2